# Categorical values in correlation matrix

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, feature-selection, continuous-data

I'm doing a feature selection in R, trying to find the variables which correlates with the target value most.

I use `cor()` to build a matrix. The problem - some of my variable as well as the target value are factors.

I converted them all to numeric, assuming the levels will represent the different factors in the matrix.
**The problem:** one variable which I think should be highly correlated with the target value (got a high score in RF importance) got only 7% in the matrix. *(if to be specific, I work on the Titanic dataset and created "title" variable to predict the survivors)*

Is converting factors to numeric values a good practice for a correlation matrix? Can it corrupt the data somehow?

Comment: Suppose your factor has levels A, B and C. Your procedure assumes that the difference between A and C is twice the difference between A and B and B and C. Is that what you want to assume?

Comment: In my case, almost all who is C survived, half of B survived and almost all who is A died.

Comment: Instead of computing correlation on the categorical variables,  it might be more reasonable to ask "Is the proportion of survivors different for the different categories?"

Comment: Make sense. This is what I did so far with data visualization tools. But I thought a correlation algorithm will be more objective than my eyes, so to speak.